# How to detect when a new object is spawned or deleted from unity for scoring/points?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to make a score/points system for my game where every time an object has been destroyed the score increases, I'm using a set of assets named GDG_Assets which allow you to create destructible environmental objects. when an object is hit the main object is made invisible and a model of the object broken up is spawned in. I want to know how I can detect when these new models have been spawned in and how I can implement them into my code?
The "Amount" ints are where the number of objects destroyed/spawned will be stored to give a score. I could detect collision with my projectile but the issue with this is that the way the game is designed an explosion causes a chain reaction causing other objects to be destroyed. any ideas or code improvements would be much appreciated.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class scoreCount : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text countText;



    public int eggCount;
    public int barrelCount;
    public int cubeCount;

    //game objects
    public GameObject Egg_000;
    public GameObject Barrel_000;
    public GameObject Cube01_000;

    //amount of objects destroyed
    public int barrelAmount;
    public int eggAmount;
    public int cubeAmount;

    private int count;
    private int egg;
    private int barrel;
    private int cube;

    // Initializing points of each object
    void Start () {
        count = 0;
        egg = 100;
        barrel = 75;
        cube = 200;
        countText.text = "Score: " + count.ToString ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        //multiplies amount of objects destroyed by points
        eggCount = egg * eggAmount;
        barrelCount = barrel * barrelAmount;
        cubeCount = cube * cubeAmount;

        //determines final score
        count = eggCount + barrelCount + cubeCount;
        countText.text = "Score: " + count.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: "when an object is hit the main object is made invisible and a model of the object broken up is spawned in" - when this happens, in your code for the model being broken up and destroyed, you should increment a global state variable by 1. You can refer to this documentation on keeping score. https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter-tutorial/counting-points-and-displaying-score

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply I'll take a look at the link and get back to you on if it worked.

Comment: In general, you're looking for an event or method you can override when the swap occurs. In addition to the suggestion from @Jon , the other thing to look into is the Unity events system: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/events. That's a more general solution to "how do I get notified of 'x' happening"

Answer (score 1):

You should make that more event driven instead of having it in `Update`

therefore I would implement an `enum`.

```
public enum DestructableType
{
    Egg,
    Barrel,
    Cube,
}
```

Than I would change your class like

```
public class scoreCount : MonoBehaviour 
{
    [Header("Components")]
    public Text countText;

    [Header("Prefabs")]
    public DestructableObject Egg_000;
    public DestructableObject Barrel_000;
    public DestructableObject Cube01_000;

    // I didn't see what those are used for
    /*
    public int eggCount;
    public int barrelCount;
    public int cubeCount;
    */

    [Header("amount of objects destroyed")]
    public int barrelAmount;
    public int eggAmount;
    public int cubeAmount;

    // Simply adjust those in the inspector as well and give them default values
    [Header("points values")]
    [SerializeField] private int egg = 100;
    [SerializeField] private int barrel = 75;
    [SerializeField] private int cube = 200;

    // Will be 0 by default anyway
    private int count;

    // Initializing points of each object
    private void Start () 
    {
        // Only thing needed to be set in Start
        // though even this you could simply do in that Text component already
        countText.text = "Score: " + count.ToString ();
    }

    // Called by the DestructableObjects when destroyed
    public void ObjectsDestroyed(DestructableType type)
    {
        // I didn't know which values you really need in the end
        // actually the lines with count += xyz; would be enough I guess
        switch(type)
        {
            case Egg:
                eggCount += egg;
                eggAmount++;
                count += egg;
                break;

            case Barrel:
                barrelCount += barrel;
                barrelAmount++;
                count += barrel;
                break;

            case Cube:
                cubeCount += cube;
                cubeAmount++;
                count += cube;
                break;
        }

        countText.text = "Score: " + count.ToString();
    }
}
```

And on your Prefabs add an additional component

```
public class DestructableObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Adjust this through the inspector
    public DestructableType Type;

    private void OnDestroy ()
    {
        FindObjectOfType<scoreCount>().ObjectsDestroyed(Type);
    }
}
```

Comment: so it turns out your code would have worked perfectly but the problem is that the destructible library I'm using spawns in all objects into the game on start and just toggles if they're visible or not is there any way to detect this?

Comment: You could replace `OnDestroy` by `OnDisable` which is also called everytime the according GameObject is set inactive.